# How to shoot multiple bullets at the same time in different directions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'd like to know how could I shoot multiple bullets in diffent directions at the same time?

I have this gameobject as you can see in the image below, and it has 4 spawn points which spaws the bullets.

[image: this image]

So when this gameobject is hit by a specific enemy, it shoots at the four directions at the same time. I've already tried something like this, but it's not working. I'm pretty new at Unity. This script is attached to this gameobject.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DanoCruz : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Damage = 1f;

    public GameObject Projetil;
    public GameObject SpawnProjetil1;
    public GameObject SpawnProjetil2;
    public GameObject SpawnProjetil3;
    public GameObject SpawnProjetil4;

    public float ProjetVelocity = 1f;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.transform.tag == "projetil")
        {
          GameObject tiro = Instantiate(Projetil,SpawnProjetil1.transform.position,SpawnProjetil1.transform.rotation);// it spawns on the left

            tiro = Instantiate(Projetil, SpawnProjetil2.transform.position, SpawnProjetil2.transform.rotation);// it spawns on the right
            tiro = Instantiate(Projetil, SpawnProjetil3.transform.position, SpawnProjetil3.transform.rotation);// it spawns behind
            tiro = Instantiate(Projetil, SpawnProjetil4.transform.position, SpawnProjetil4.transform.rotation);// it spawns in the front

            Destroy(other.gameObject);

        }
    }
}
```

The bullets don't move. How could I solve it?

Comment: Is there a script for your bullets that handles their movement? If so, can you post the codes?

Comment: @Kaynn No, there isn't. I have just this one, that is attached to the object which shoots the bullets

Comment: How do you move the bullet? Do they use an script that applies a constant transform translation? Or do you use a Rigidbody?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer seems to have a lot of repeated code. We could clean that up a bit with

```
if (other.transform.tag == "projetil")
{
    List<GameObject> tiros = new List<GameObject>
    {
        Instantiate(Projetil, SpawnProjetil1.transform.position, SpawnProjetil1.transform.rotation),
        Instantiate(Projetil, SpawnProjetil2.transform.position, SpawnProjetil2.transform.rotation),
        Instantiate(Projetil, SpawnProjetil3.transform.position, SpawnProjetil3.transform.rotation),
        Instantiate(Projetil, SpawnProjetil4.transform.position, SpawnProjetil4.transform.rotation),
    };

    foreach (GameObject tiro in tiros)
    {
        Rigidbody rigiProj = tiro.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rigiProj.velocity = tiro.transform.forward * ProjetVelocity * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

This way, you do not have to check the tag of the spawned projectile, since those should never change.

Answer (score 0):

I've done the following and know everything is working:

```
if (other.transform.tag == "projetil")
        {


            if (SpawnProjetil1.tag == "Spaw1")//right
            {
                GameObject tiro = Instantiate(Projetil, SpawnProjetil1.transform.position, SpawnProjetil1.transform.rotation);
                Rigidbody rigiProj = tiro.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
                rigiProj.velocity = SpawnProjetil1.transform.forward * ProjetVelocity * Time.deltaTime;
            }

            if (SpawnProjetil2.tag == "Spaw2")//left
            {
                GameObject tiro = Instantiate(Projetil, SpawnProjetil2.transform.position, SpawnProjetil2.transform.rotation);
                Rigidbody rigiProj = tiro.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
                rigiProj.velocity = SpawnProjetil2.transform.forward * ProjetVelocity * Time.deltaTime;
            }


            if (SpawnProjetil3.tag == "Spaw3")//behind
            {
                GameObject tiro = Instantiate(Projetil, SpawnProjetil3.transform.position, SpawnProjetil3.transform.rotation);
                Rigidbody rigiProj = tiro.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
                rigiProj.velocity = SpawnProjetil3.transform.forward * ProjetVelocity * Time.deltaTime;
            }



            if (SpawnProjetil4.tag == "Spaw4")//front
            {
                GameObject tiro = Instantiate(Projetil, SpawnProjetil4.transform.position, SpawnProjetil4.transform.rotation);
                Rigidbody rigiProj = tiro.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
                rigiProj.velocity = SpawnProjetil4.transform.forward * ProjetVelocity * Time.deltaTime;
            }


            Destroy(other.gameObject);

        }
```